# JavaScript Adding changing Number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add two values together

```
let coorH = $e.deltaX;
let currentX = this.xPos;
newX = currentX + coorH
```

coorH is obviously changing as i move my mouse but I only want to add the current value of coorH to currentX not always add the two together and then add coorH.

How would i do that?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you add a snippet showing what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: What you mean by "not always add the two together and then add coorH."  ?  You would like to add them only when one of pos will change ?  Or when both will change? ?

Comment: What i am trying to do is add the current mouse position(coorH) to the original xpos of my object(currentX).
Now, if i leave my code like that it will always add coorH to the existing sum of the two:
coorH = 5;
currentX= 10;
newX = 5+10=15;
when i move my mouse to currentX=20, it adds 20 to the existing 15 but i want it to add the 20 to the original xpos(5) so that i get 25 as a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need in that case to keep the scope of new X larger than that of the other two variables:

```
let coorH = $e.deltaX;
let currentX = this.xPos;
let newX = currentX + coorH;
```

This way newX will always be new.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
newX = parseInt(currentX) + parseInt(coorH);
```